# Удаление старых ссылок из поисковых систем или SEO заново

Tags: оптимизация, seo, sitemap

Добрый вечер, господа специалисты.

Занимаюсь SEO уже полгода, достаточно хорошо разбираюсь в оптимизации сайтов.

Теперь у меня другая задача - сайт перенесен в другой движок, соответственно все URL материалов на сайте изменились, добавлены другие страницы на сайт, но в поисковых системах появляются новые ссылки и старые остались. Как мне правильно и качественно удалить старые ссылки и сделать индекс сайта заново, с новыми страницами сайта?

P.S. В гугле могу найти ответ на этот вопрос, но лучше небольшое обсуждение, чем статья, которая не до конца ответит на мой вопрос.

Благодарю за время!

Comment: выдавать 404 для страниц, которых нет?

Comment: @naym там и так 404. Нужно удалить из поисковых систем. Скорее работа с инструментами веб-мастера в поисковых систем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой вариант закрыть старый сайт от индексации.А новый продолжать оптимизировать, оптимизировать и еще оптимизировать. Обрастать ссылками и конечно же обновляйте сайт, чуть ли не каждый день и через 7-10 дней старые ссылки уйдут. Да после переноса сайта на другой движок вам нужно удалить все данные из доп индекса.

Answer (score 1):

Для "ненужных" урлов страниц отдаете код 404 (не существует).
Для "нужных", старых с "весом" и трафиком, отдается код 301 (переехала) и получаете поней старый трафик.
Тут обсуждать даже нечего. Все есть в справке гугла и подробно.

Answer (score -1):

Тут самый правильный вариант - отлавливать старые ссылки, и с них ставить 301 редирект на новые релевантные страницы. Когда ссылки (те которые с беклинками) закончаться - поставить редирект на оставшиеся старые - на категорию (новый сайт, не главную страницу).

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score -2):

Когда много ошибок 404, это не нормально. Гугл не любит их тоже. Лучше сделать 301 редирект на главную страницу.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?